# Maximum common edge subgraph of two trees in polynomial time?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, trees

Is it possible to find a maximum common edge subgraph of two trees in polynomial time? This [paper](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/978-3-642-32589-2_10.pdf) by Akutsu et al. seems to claim so in the introduction by using a maximum weight matching algorithm.

However, this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.08509) by Grohe et al., seem to claim that computing the distance $d(G,H)$ of two trees $G,H$ is NP-hard, as shown in Theorem 3.2.

These two results are not in contradiction per se, but it seems that if they are both true then P=NP. Specifically, define $d(G,H)=\min_{\pi\in S_n}|A_G^\pi-A_H|$ where $A_G,A_H$ are the adjacency matrices of $G$ and $H$ respectively, $A^\pi$ is the matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $A_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}$ and $|M|$ is the Frobenius norm of $M$; namely, $|M|^2=\sum_{i,j}M_{ij}^2$. It should be easy to show that $d(G,H)^2=2(|E(G)|+|E(H)|-k)$ if, and only if, the maximum common edge subgraph has $k$ edges. Thus, if finding the maximum common edge subgraph of trees $G,H$ can be done in polynomial time, then $d(G,H)$ can also be computed in polynomial time in spite of being NP hard...

Answer (score 1):

The two problems are not equivalent.

Akatsu and Tamura are looking the problem of finding the maximum common *connected* subgraph. On the other hand, the graph distance problem in Grohe et al. is equivalent to finding the maximum common subgraph whether or not it is connected.

For further confirmation: if we look at the reduction from unary 3-partition in the proof of Theorem 8 in Grohe et al.'s paper, we see that it begins by looking at the problem for two path forests: one with $m$ paths of a fixed length $A$, and one with $3m$ paths of varying lengths $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{3m}$ with $\frac A4 < a_i < \frac A2$ for all $i$. (Path lengths are counted by number of vertices.) To determine if there is a common subgraph with $m(A-3)$ edges, we need to check if we can partition $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{3m}$ into $m$ triples, each adding up to $A$.

On the other hand, the maximum common *connected* subgraph can be found quickly: we just need to find the longest path in the second graph, and place it on top of one of the paths in the first graph.

Comment: Thank you Misha. On a similar note, do you know if there are any known non-trivial classes of graphs for which the computation of a maximum common edge subgraph can be done in polynomial time?

Comment: If we can't even do it for path forests, I doubt anything else could be simpler.